# BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'input-stream-name' is expected to be of type 'org.springframework.messaging.SubscribableChannel

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-kafka

I am trying to unit test spring-stream kafka code, When running the unit test I get below error
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'input-stream-name' is expected to be of type 'org.springframework.messaging.SubscribableChannel

```
public interface TestStream {
    @Input(TestStreamInputOutput.INPUT)
    SubscribableChannel inboundTestMessageRequest();

    @Output(TestStreamInputOutput.OUTPUT)
    MessageChannel outboundTestStatusResponse();
}
```

---

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("stream")
public class TestStreamServiceImplTest {

    @Autowired
    private TesttreamServiceImpl testStreamServiceImpl;
    
    @MockBean
    private TestStream  testStream;
    
    @Mock
    private MessageChannel messageChannel;
    
    @Test
    public void pushAwsEmailStatus_When_Dto_Not_Null_Success()
    {
        
        Optional<TestStatusDetailDto> testStatusDetailsDto = Optional.ofNullable(
                TestStatusDetailDto.newBuilder()
                .setMessageId("1234").setMessageStatus(TestStatusDetailDto.Sent).build());
        
        Mockito.when(testStream.outboundTestStatusResponse()).thenReturn(messageChannel);
        Mockito.when(messageChannel.send(Mockito.any(Message.class))).thenReturn(true);
        testStreamServiceImpl.pushTestStatus(testStatusDetailsDto);
        Mockito.verify(messageChannel,Mockito.times(1)).send(Mockito.any(Message.class));
    }
}
```

---

## input kafka

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input-stream-name.contentType=application/*+avro
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input-stream-name.destination=icom-in-message-status-events

## output kafka

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input-stream-name-out.contentType=application/*+avro
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input-stream-name-out.destination=icom-hk-message-status-events

---

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-schema</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

---

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

Comment: I have had this happen when registering a `NewTopic` bean whose topic name was the same as the bean name, e.g. `@Bean public NewTopic test() { return TopicBuilder.name("test").build(); }`. I think under some circumstances Spring tries to treat topic names as bean names, and the collision confuses Spring.